# How to ignore timeout error on Cypress exec()

Tags: timeout, exec, cypress

I use exec() function on cypress but I get timeout error sometimes even if it works properly.

Is there any possibility ignore this timeout error?

I do not want to see this error. I want to see always pass/true in any case.

Comment: Please add your code and your error message to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into `failOnNonZeroExit` options flag. It determines whether to fail if the command exits with a non-zero code.

```js
cy.exec('some commands', { failOnNonZeroExit: false })
```

Or, You can also pass a `timeout` options object with `cy.exec()`, something like:

```js
cy.exec('some commands', { timeout: 10000 }) //timeout for 10 seconds
```

Comment: I tried it but did not work. I did everything on the document of cypress.

Comment: `failOnNonZeroExit: false` does not work, I still got timeout errors, however it helped me to manage exec error as I want and not from cypress